# Singly Linked List Display for checking in C

Tags: c

I am implementing Singly Linked List on my program. Now I have this display function to display what is inside my singly linked list. Now the problem is when I call my display function. It only prints the head. For example `20-->NULL`. Display function for checking if I implement Singly linked list correctly.

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}*start=NULL;

void display()
{
 struct node *new_node;
 printf("The Linked List : ");
 new_node=start;
 while(new_node!=NULL)
   {
   printf("%d--->",new_node->data);
   new_node=new_node->next;
   }
  printf("NULL");
}



void creat(int num)
{
      struct node *new_node,*current;

      new_node=malloc(sizeof(struct node));


      new_node->data=num;
      new_node->next=NULL;

      if(start==NULL)
      {
      start=new_node;
      current=new_node;
      }
      else
      {
      current->next=new_node;
      current=new_node;
      }
      //printf("%d->",new_node->data);
}

void main()
{

    int binrange,max=100,n,i,divi;
    int inp[4];
    clrscr();
    printf("enter 5 numbers: ");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&inp[i]);
    }
    printf("\nenter range: ");
    scanf("%d",&binrange);
    n=max/binrange;
    divi=max/n;

    for(i=0;i<=max;i++)
    {
        if(i%divi==0 && i>0)
        {
            //create nodes here
            //store i into nodes
            creat(i);


        }


    }

    display();
    getch();
}
```

Comment: What entries you actually insert to the list? (Hint, add debug prints to `creat`). Also, check return value of `scanf`, because if there is parse error, your `inp` and `bindrange` will be left uninitialized.

Comment: Try to pass the Head Pointer to the Display function and assign that to the new_node variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `current` is a ***local*** variable inside the `creat` function, and it goes out of scope (and "disappears") every time the `creat` function exits.

That means two things: The variable will always be uninitialized everytime you call the function, and by dereferencing the (uninitialized) pointer you have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The reason for the undefined behavior is just because the variable is uninitialized. Uninitialized non-static local variables have an *indeterminate* value, and in reality if will be seemingly random. So what you are doing is taking this pointer that points to a "random" location and write to it.

There are three possible solutions: One is to make the `current` variable `static`, the other is to make it global, and the third is to not have it at all and find the end every time the function is called. Oh, and if you go for one of the two first, you should probably rename it to `end` (or something similar) because that's what it is, a pointer to the end of the list.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you're defining

```
int inp[4];
```

and then you're reading

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&inp[i]);
    }
```

Clearly past the allocated memory when `i` is 4 [array indexing in c starts from `0`]. So, [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

---

EDIT:

Also, as Mr. Joachim Pileborg mentioned, `struct node * current` is local to the `creat()` function, as goes out-of-scope each and every time the function is finished.

Side Effects:

- Every time you start with a fresh `current` having garbage [you did not initialize].
- You'll be dereferencing uninitialized memory.

You need a way to store the value. Otherwise, again, UB.

P.S - Both the cases cause UB in their own ways. :-)